# sphinx index fail, and ask me to restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it

Tags: mysql, indexing, sphinx

mysql config `my.ini` default query_cache_type=0 .
I have already set `sql_query_pre = SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF` in `sphinx.conf`.I think it is not good to turn cache while indexing.But sphinx still asking me to turn on cache...

error detail:

win7 x64, sphinx 2.1.7

```
I:\sphinx\bin>I:\sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --all --config I:\sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.1.7-id64-release (r4638)
Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file 'I:\sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'test1'...
ERROR: index 'test1': sql_query_pre[1]: Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it
 (DSN=mysql://root:***@localhost:3306/test).
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.018 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'rt'...
total 0 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 0 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'message' you are receiving is coming from mysql - not from sphinx. indexer just runs the commands as provided and reports/uses the results.

Basically mysql is telling yo the query cache is already disabled. its not enabled globally.

So trying to turn if off for just the (indexing) session, fails, because its not on. If its not enabled in teh first place you cant disable it!

http://www.big.info/2013/04/error-code-1651-query-cache-is-disabled.html

Its telling you NEED to turn it on globally first, before you are ABLE to turn if off.

Maybe mysql could just silently fail to turn it off, rather than giving an error, but thats a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where I was seeing this error, and it was actually preventing the `indexer --all` command from generating indices. I went to the XAMPP Control Panel and clicked on the `Config` button for the `MySQL` module. This opened the file `my.ini` in Notepad. I added the following line to the `[mysqld]` section in the file:

```
query_cache_type = 1
```

Then I restarted the MySQL service. The value of query_cache_type was now displayed as ON, and the `indexer --all` command successfully generated indices.